# Snap Raster and same cell size still lead to slight differences between rasters

Tags: raster, snapping, alignment, cell-size

I'm working in ArcMap 10.6.1, where I've been trying to make the cells of two rasters (let's call them raster A and raster B) line up perfectly with each other using the Snap Raster and Cell Size environment settings. Specifically, I've clipped both rasters to a study area, using raster A as Snap Raster and Cell Size. They both have WGS84 as coordinate system. However, there are still slight alignment differences between the rasters, leading to small slivers of data when I try to combine the two in a Raster Calculator. I've already tried the suggested solution that I've seen online of disabling background processing, but this didn't solve the problem for me. I've also tried using Resample instead of the Cell Size environment setting, but this did not work either. What other problems could there be that I haven't thought of yet? If it's relevant, raster A has a cell size of 30x30 arcsec.

I've attached images of raster A, raster B and the slivers of data resulting from the Raster Calculator (in this image, raster A and B have the same values in each cell, which should give a resulting raster with only values of 0, since I've subtracted raster A from raster B. However, instead there are mostly 0 values, with some non-zero values in between)

[image: Raster A]

[image: Raster B]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I didn't completely solve this problem, but found a work-around. Rather than using the cell size and snap raster environment settings during a Clip operation, I ended up having to first resample raster A to the cell size of raster B with raster B as a snap raster. Then I clipped both. This took a lot more time to process, since I now had to resample the entire raster A, but at least it got the desired output.